# Redis Client not connecting to Redis server via HAProxy

Tags: redis, haproxy, jedis, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I'm facing an issue while connecting to Redis server via HAProxy using Jedis as a redis client.
Everything works fine when Redis server is directly connected to but, the same is not working via HAProxy. Both HAProxy and Redis services are running on their specific ports, HAProxy on port 80 & Redis server on 6379. 
We are running this setup on EC2 instances and all the necessary ports are open.

HAProxy Configuration is

```
frontend http-in
bind *:80
default_backend redis-server

backend redis-server
    stats   enable
    server redis-server1 x.x.x.x:6379 check inter 1000 fall 3 rise 2
    server redis-server2 x.x.x.x:6379 check inter 1000 fall 3 rise 2
```

Jedis Clinet code is:

```
 try {
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis(hostname, port);
    jedis.set("key", "Redis-Test-Value");
    System.out.println("value from redis node is: " + jedis.get("key"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception is " + e);
}
```

Exception message that gets thrown is - `redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply: H`

Can someone point out what am I missing and point to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

> frontend http-in

Redis isn't an HTTP server, so serving it up as one won't work. Since this is a server administration issue, not a programming issue, try the list or serverfault.com for any additional questions.